# Flask-Dance facebook invalid redirect_url

Tags: docker, flask, facebook-oauth, flask-dance

I am using Flask-Dance for facebook login.

Here is blueprint file

```
from flask import redirect, url_for
from flask_dance.contrib.facebook import make_facebook_blueprint, facebook

facebook_bp = make_facebook_blueprint(
    redirect_url='http://api.domain.com/auth/social/facebook/authorized'
)

@facebook_bp.route('')
def index():
    if not facebook.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for("facebook.login"))
    resp = facebook.get("/me")
    return resp.text
```

And below is main app file

```
from api.auth.facebook import facebook_bp

...
app.register_blueprint(facebook_bp, url_prefix='/auth/social')
```

When I request to `https://api.domain.com/auth/social` it redirects me to facebook, which says that redirect_url is blocked.

The facebook url that flask-dance opens is something linke this `facebook.com/...&redirect_uri=http://api/auth/social/facebook/authorized&...`

I have even tried to add `redirect_url` in blueprint configs, but the same thing there.

The app is deployed with docker compose nginx and gunicorn.

Answer (score 0):

kindly check that

```
if not facebook.authorized:
    #write redirect_to value as url_for(blueprint.route)
    facebook.blueprint.redirect_to='blueprint.route'
    return redirect(url_for("facebook.login"))
resp = facebook.get("/me")
assert resp.ok, resp.text
return "You are {name} on Facebook".format(name=resp.json()["name"])
```

in my case turns out redirect_to is always none ! if I did it as the following:

```
        app.register_blueprint(facebook_bp, url_prefix="/login",redirect_to='user_routes.LoginPage')
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that the `redirect_uri` query parameter doesn't match the domain that your Flask app is running on. That indicates that Flask (not Flask-Dance, but Flask itself) is getting incorrect information (or possibly no information) about the server it's running on. This information is necessary for handling OAuth securely.

Read through [the Flask-Dance documentation about proxies and HTTPS](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/proxies.html), as well as [the Flask documentation about proxies](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#deploying-proxy-setups). Once Flask is able to correctly determine where it's running, Flask-Dance should generate the `redirect_uri` correctly.